# Substitution Algorithm in Haskell

Tags: haskell, substitution

I'm trying to write a substitution algorithm in Haskell.
I have defined a polymorphic data type `Subst a` with a single constructor `S::[(String, a)] -> Subst a` as so:

```
data Subst a = S [(String, a)]
```

I now want to write a function `single::String -> a -> Subst a` for constructing a substitution for only a single variable

This is what I tried:

```
single::String -> a -> Subst a
single s1 (Subst a) = s1 a
```

However, I'm getting this error: `Not in scope: data constructor 'Subst'`

Does anyone have insight to what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: n.b. if you create a data type that contains only "one" value and only one constructor, you can use `newtype` for efficiency. `newtype Subst a = Subst [(String, a)]`. Conventionally, for newtypes, one usually names the constructor to be the same as the type name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data constructor is not the same thing as the *type constuctor*

In your code the *type constructor* is `Subst` the *data constructor* is `S`

Type constructors are used to create new types, e.g. in `data Foo = Foo (Maybe Int)` `Maybe` is a *type* constructor, `Foo` is the data constructor (as well as the type constructor, but they can be named differently as you discovered). *Data* constructors are used to create instances of types (also don't confuse this with creating an instance of a polymorphic type, e.g. `Int -> Int` is an instance of `a -> a`).

So you need to use `S` when you want to pattern match in your `single` function. Not `Subst`.

Hopefully that makes sense, if not, please tell me :)

P.S. data constructors are, for all intents and purposes, functions, which means you can do the same things with them that you'd typically do with functions. E.g. you can do `map Bar [a,b,c]` and it will apply the data constructor to each element.

Answer (score 3):

```
single :: String -> a -> Subst a
single str a = S [(str, a)]
```

The `[(str, a)]` part creates a list with one element.  That element is a tuple (or "pair"), with `str` as the left part of the tuple and `a` as the right part of the tuple.  The above function then wraps that single-element list in the `S` constructor to create a value of type `Subst` a.

The result is a list that contains the rule for a single substitution from `str` to the value `a`.